# Drawing empty horizontal bars using divs

Tags: html, css, frontend, bootstrap-4, web-frontend

I want to draw 2 divs like the one shown in the below wireframe example. The latter one (black bar) being empty of content. How would I draw these 2 divs using Bootstrap 4?

Following is my effort at this:

```
<div class="icons_div">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2"> 
      <div class="icon">
        <i class="fa fa-circle"> </i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <div class="icon"> <i class="fa fa-circle"> </i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-globe"> </i> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"> <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"> </i> </div> </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"> <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-home"> </i> </div> </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"> <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-trash"> </i> </div> </div>
  </div>
</div> <br> <br>
```

Following is my re-tried code after Web Dev's Comments:

CSS:
    .icon-bar
    {
      width: 100%;
      background-color: black;
      overflow: auto;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .icon-bar a
    {
      float: left;
      text-align: center;
      width: 20%;
      padding: 12px 0;
      transition: all;
      color: white;
      font-size: 36px;
    }

```
.icon-bar a:hover
{
  background-color: #000;
}
.active
{
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.icons_div
{
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: max-content;
}

.icon
{
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 15px;
  display: initial;
}

.fa
{
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="icons_div">
        <div class="row bg-secondary">
            <div class="col-sm-2"> 
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle"> </i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="icon"> <i class="fa fa-circle"> </i></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-globe"> </i> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2"> <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"> </i> </div> </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2"> <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-home"> </i> </div> </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2"> <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-trash"> </i> </div> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col bg-dark" style="height: 40px;"></div>
    </div>
</div> <br> <br>
```

[Wireframe of divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BF6ig.jpg)

Output from Retry:
[image: Output after retry]

Answer (score 2):

In that case, you just add the `bg-secondary` class to the first row to give it the grey background color and then create a second row-column pair underneath and add the `bg-dark` to the empty column there as well as `style="height: 40px;"` to give it the desired height.

Here's the code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="container">
    <div class="icons_div">
        <div class="row bg-secondary">
            <div class="col-sm-2"> 
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle"> </i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="icon"> <i class="fa fa-circle"> </i></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-globe"> </i> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2"> <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"> </i> </div> </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2"> <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-home"> </i> </div> </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2"> <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-trash"> </i> </div> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col bg-dark" style="height: 40px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, the black bar is fully prepared, But the grey bar (top one) however did not expand on the full screen, Also I'm doing this on a container-fluid and not the container

Comment: So, you want the top bar to be the full width of the screen, correct?

Comment: Exactly, and I have already used the container-fluid instead of the container class, but to no help

Comment: Please update your question with the complete code you have.

Comment: Oh, i see. You want a bar as a menu. Ok.

Comment: Updated it again, you can check the code as well as the output

Comment: What is the reason you are using the div with the `icons_div` class? What exactly are you trying to achieve using that div? Please list ALL of the reasons.

Comment: The purpose of icons_div is, as explained by it's name, to include icons only  in the bar

Comment: In that case, you just remove that div and the problem is fixed. You don't need that. The row is your bar. But I suspect you might have more reasons which you haven't explained yet.

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: This is the answer where I posted the code that you started using for your other questions without accepting this answer first.